# What is LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp___strdup?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I am moving a class from one project to another in Visual Studio 2015 and this is the error that I get. I cannot find any other examples of this specific error.

Comment: can you tell where the error appears?

Comment: attention to **How to Ask** when asking question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__imp_` is `__declspec(dllimport)`, and the next underscore indicates that the function is `extern "C"` and `__cdecl`, leaving `_strdup` as the function name.  Therefore, going by the MSDN documentation linked in the comments, the symbol `__imp___strdup` is:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) char* __cdecl _strdup(const char* strSource);
```

This function requires the header `<string.h>`

It would appear that the project you moved your class into doesn't use one of the MS libraries that contains the function, for some reason.  That's my guess, at least.  Try checking each project's properties and seeing if they use the same `.lib` files?