# Use "extern __declspec(dllimport)" in Cython

Tags: dll, cython, dllimport

Can I use `extern __declspec(dllimport)` in Cython? I am trying to wrap `embree` in Windows, but am not sure I can dynamically link in Cython.

I read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18515275/can-cython-code-be-compiled-to-a-dll-so-c-application-can-call-it) which is great for changing C/C++ and header files directly, but I'm not sure how to implement this in a `.pxd` file.

For example, the [Embree 2.17.7 x64](https://github.com/embree/embree/releases/tag/v2.17.7) header `rtcore.h` defines `RTCORE_API` as

```c
#ifndef RTCORE_API
#if defined(_WIN32) && !defined(EMBREE_STATIC_LIB)
#    define RTCORE_API extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)
#else
#    define RTCORE_API extern "C"
#endif
#endif
```

However, these are left off the function signatures that use them in the [pyembree](https://github.com/scopatz/pyembree) pxd file `rtcore.pxd`. This seems consistent with the [Cython docs](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html), which state to

> Leave out any platform-specific extensions to C declarations such as __declspec()

However, even if I point the pyembree `setup.py` file to my downloaded embree DLL by changing the line

```py
ext.libraries = ["embree"]
```

to

```py
ext.libraries = [""C:/Program Files/Intel/Embree v2.17.7 x64/bin/embree""]
```

I still get 3 linking errors:

```sh
mesh_construction.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_rtcMapBuffer
mesh_construction.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_rtcNewTriangleMesh
mesh_construction.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_rtcUnmapBuffer
build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyembree\mesh_construction.cp38-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

I know from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38646896/what-is-lnk2001-unresolved-external-symbol-imp-strdup) and the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2001?view=msvc-160) that `__imp_` related linker errors are due to not finding DLLs. However, you can see in `rtcore_geometry.h` that it is defined:

[image: rtcore_geometry.h]

and in `rtcore_geometry.pxd` it is defined:

[image: rtcore_geometry.pxd]

the only difference being that the `.pxd` file does not include `RTCORE_API` in the signature.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this issue so `pyembree` will build?

**EDIT:** It should also be noted, I have added

```py
# distutils: language=c++
```

to all my `.pyx` and `.pxd` files. [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43521852/cython-dynamic-library-linking) was also reviewed, but it did not solve my problem.

**UPDATE:** Adding the `embree.lib` file to my local `pyembree/embree2` folder and updating `setup.py` to

```py
ext.libraries = ["pyembree/embree2/*"]
```

permits the code to compile via

```sh
py setup.py build_ext -i
```

However, the packages do not load:

```py
>>> import pyembree
>>> from pyembree import rtcore_scene
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing rtcore_scene: The specified module could not be found.
```

Do I need to define the "subpackages" in my `setup.py`? This is my current `setup.py`:

```py
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

import numpy as np
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

include_path = [np.get_include()]

ext_modules = cythonize(
    'pyembree/*.pyx',
    language_level=3,
    include_path=include_path)

for ext in ext_modules:
    ext.include_dirs = include_path
    ext.libraries = [
        "pyembree/embree2/*",
    ]

setup(
    name="pyembree",
    version='0.1.6',
    cmdclass = {"build_ext": build_ext},
    ext_modules=ext_modules,
    zip_safe=False,
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data = True
)
```

and the directory structure is as follows (`pyembree` is the top-level folder in my `.venv\lib\site-packages` folder of my project):

```
pyembree
│   .authors.yml
│   .gitignore
│   .mailmap
│   AUTHORS
│   CHANGELOG.rst
│   LICENSE
│   MANIFEST.in
│   pyproject.toml
│   README.rst
│   setup.py
│   
├───build
│   └───temp.win-amd64-3.8
│       └───Release
│           └───pyembree
│                   mesh_construction.cp38-win_amd64.exp
│                   mesh_construction.cp38-win_amd64.lib
│                   mesh_construction.obj
│                   rtcore.cp38-win_amd64.exp
│                   rtcore.cp38-win_amd64.lib
│                   rtcore.obj
│                   rtcore_scene.cp38-win_amd64.exp
│                   rtcore_scene.cp38-win_amd64.lib
│                   rtcore_scene.obj
│                   triangles.cp38-win_amd64.exp
│                   triangles.cp38-win_amd64.lib
│                   triangles.obj
│
├───pyembree
│   │   mesh_construction.cp38-win_amd64.pyd
│   │   mesh_construction.cpp
│   │   mesh_construction.h
│   │   mesh_construction.pyx
│   │   rtcore.cp38-win_amd64.pyd
│   │   rtcore.cpp
│   │   rtcore.pxd
│   │   rtcore.pyx
│   │   rtcore_geometry.pxd
│   │   rtcore_geometry_user.pxd
│   │   rtcore_ray.pxd
│   │   rtcore_scene.cp38-win_amd64.pyd
│   │   rtcore_scene.cpp
│   │   rtcore_scene.pxd
│   │   rtcore_scene.pyx
│   │   triangles.cp38-win_amd64.pyd
│   │   triangles.cpp
│   │   triangles.pyx
│   │   __init__.pxd
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   ├───embree2
│   │       embree.lib
│   │       rtcore.h
│   │       rtcore.isph
│   │       rtcore_builder.h
│   │       rtcore_geometry.h
│   │       rtcore_geometry.isph
│   │       rtcore_geometry_user.h
│   │       rtcore_geometry_user.isph
│   │       rtcore_ray.h
│   │       rtcore_ray.isph
│   │       rtcore_scene.h
│   │       rtcore_scene.isph
│   │       rtcore_version.h
│   │       tbb.lib
│   │       tbbmalloc.lib
│   │
│   └───__pycache__
│           __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│
└───tests
        test_intersection.py
```

Comment: What's the contents of your .pxd file? You usually do `cdef extern from "header.h":`. That includes the header into your Cython-generated C file. Thus `__declspec` isn't relevant because Cython doesn't need to know about it, and it's defined correctly in the included header.

Comment: @Davidw Thanks for your help! The `pxd` file is located here: https://github.com/scopatz/pyembree/tree/master/pyembree. Let me know if there's a better way to transfer this to you.

Comment: I don't know the answer (sorry), but I'm pretty sure `__declspec` in Cython isn't your problem

Comment: @DavidW I actually have an update. I'll add it to the question, if you can take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code functions properly once I literally hand-copy and paste over the `DLL`s into the generated `.egg` folder in my `.venv\Lib\site-packages` folder:

```
pyembree-0.1.6-py3.8-win-amd64.egg
├───EGG-INFO
│       dependency_links.txt
│       native_libs.txt
│       not-zip-safe
│       PKG-INFO
│       SOURCES.txt
│       top_level.txt
│       
└───pyembree
    │   embree.dll
    │   freeglut.dll
    │   mesh_construction.cp38-win_amd64.pyd
    │   mesh_construction.cpp
    │   mesh_construction.py
    │   rtcore.cp38-win_amd64.pyd
    │   rtcore.cpp
    │   rtcore.py
    │   rtcore_scene.cp38-win_amd64.pyd
    │   rtcore_scene.cpp
    │   rtcore_scene.py
    │   tbb.dll
    │   tbbmalloc.dll
    │   triangles.cp38-win_amd64.pyd
    │   triangles.cpp
    │   triangles.py
    │   __init__.py
    │
    └───__pycache__
            mesh_construction.cpython-38.pyc
            rtcore.cpython-38.pyc
            rtcore_scene.cpython-38.pyc
            triangles.cpython-38.pyc
            __init__.cpython-38.pyc
```

However, how can I tell `python` to copy and paste these `DLL`s over? Can I put something in my `setup.py` file?

**Edit:** Per @ead's comments, the `setup.py` can be updated to the following to automate copying the DLLs over the the right folder (thanks @ead!):

```py
import os
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

import numpy as np
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext


include_path = [
    np.get_include(),
]

ext_modules = cythonize("pyembree/*.pyx", language_level=3, include_path=include_path)

for ext in ext_modules:
    ext.include_dirs = include_path
    ext.libraries = [
        "pyembree/embree2/lib/embree",
        "pyembree/embree2/lib/tbb",
        "pyembree/embree2/lib/tbbmalloc",
    ]

setup(
    name="pyembree",
    version="0.1.6",
    cmdclass={"build_ext": build_ext},
    ext_modules=ext_modules,
    zip_safe=False,
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    package_data={"pyembree": ["*.cpp", "*.dll"]},
)
```

Comment: That are examples how dll can be distributed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62723124/5769463 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/63837811/5769463. You need to define 'package_data' to include dll and libs.

Comment: @ead I was wrong, your solution does work. I needed some time to review it. Thank you very much!